# How to increment a counter using an image.src in an if else function?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a `rock paper scissors` game with Javascript.

```
var boutonLancer = document.getElementById('lancer');

var images = [document.getElementById('imageP1'), 
document.getElementById('imageP2')];

var scoreP1 = document.getElementById('scoreP1');
var scoreP2 = document.getElementById('scoreP2');

var ciseaux = "../Images/ciseaux.png";
var feuille = "../Images/feuille.png";
var pierre = "../Images/pierre.png";

var compteurP1 = 0;
var compteurP2 = 0;


boutonLancer.onclick = function(e) {
    var lancer = [Math.floor(Math.random()*(3 - 1 + 1) + 1), Math.floor(Math.random()*(3 - 1 + 1) + 1)];



for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
    switch (lancer[i]) {
        case 1: images[i].src = ciseaux;
            break;
        case 2: images[i].src = feuille;
            break;
        case 3: images[i].src = pierre;
            break;
    }
}

console.log(images[0].src);
console.log(images[1].src);

if (images[0].src === ciseaux) {
    compteurP1 += 1;
    scoreP1.innerHTML = compteurP1;
}

console.log(compteurP1);
}
```

The main part of the game is working correctly : my images changes when I put on the button. 
After that, I wanted to create a counter for the score but when I do my if..else with the image.src, the counter doesn't increment.

I put the console.log to see what happen when I click the button : 
the images[i].src are corrects but the counter is always equal to 0.
No error, just always 0.

PS : it's working when I write if (images[0].src = ciseaux) but the first images[0] is always a 'ciseaux' (cissors) of course, and it's not what I want...

NB : I simplify the test of the if just to try.

For the test, this is my html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <title>Pierre Feuille Ciseaux</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<h1>Pierre, feuille, ciseaux</h1>
<input id="lancer" type="button">

<div id="pfc">
    <img id="imageP1" src="Images/ciseaux.png">
    <img id="imageP2" src="Images/ciseaux.png">
</div>

<div id="score">
    <div id="scoreP1">0</div>
    <div id="scoreP2">0</div>
</div>




<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you provide your html file too?

Comment: @Ricola Thank you for your test but it still doesn't work with me... Which browser do you use? I'm on chrome.

Comment: FYI: Rock, Paper, Scissors

Answer (score 0):

If you extend your console.log, your will see, that your compare doesn't work:

```
console.log(images[0].src, ciseaux);
```

will show you something like this, depending on your environment:

> https://xl2mc.csb.app/Images/ciseaux.png ../Images/ciseaux.png

As you see, if you ask for the source of the image, the full url will be returned. You could e.g. do your compare for the sub part of that string.

Comment: Ok thank you westor!!! It was that. I copy the exact return of the console.log in my condition and it works. It's bizarre because I already tried that before but it didn't work.... Whatever... lol

Comment: OK, you're welcome. Please would you vote and accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
var ciseaux = "../Images/ciseaux.png";
```

Is using a relative path to your image, whilst the real src value is an absolute path.

Change your ciseaux value to be the full absolute path to the image.